# TFS Best Practices Project Hierarchy

Tags: tfs

I've recently installed and started using TFS. Mainly using for source repository initially and then will get into using the Work Item features. I'm moving from using Vault as repository and have some questions on best practices for setting up the project structure.

```
My current structure from Vault is:
Projects
- CustomerName1
 -- Application1
 -- Application2
- CustomerName2
 -- Application1
 -- Application2
```

Can I have a smiliar structure in TFS? Is there any good documentation that has real examples and 
instructions on how to set this up? From what I see is all real basic and the books I have don't have real-life repository examples that mimic the structure I have.

I have created a new Team Project called CustomerName1, then added other Team Projects, Application1, underneath CustomerName1. However, I lose on the Application1 the separate folders like Work Items, Documents, Reports, and Builds.

So this doesn't appear set-up correctly.

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

A few questions for clarification.

Do you have *any* shared assemblies between Customer1 and Customer2? If so, put a single Team Project and then add sub-folders in source control explorer for Customer1\App1, Customer1\App2, etc, etc. Also a shared libraries or some such parallel to the CustomerX folders.

Do you have an existing branch/merge strategy?

You will have shared SharePoint sites, Builds, WorkItems, Reports, and Documents by default for the Team Project. You will have shared TFS Databases in SQL (effecting WorkItem numbers) for Team Project Collections.

You can, however, set permissions for any user/group to folders via Source Control Explorer.